# Etale local isomorphism to the tangent cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

Let $X$ be a scheme and $p\in X$ a closed point.  We say that $(X,p)$ is etale locally isomorphic to $(Y,q)$ if there exists an etale neighborhood of $p$ in $X$, and etale neighborhood of $q$ in $Y$, and an isomorphism between them.

Note that etale maps induce isomorphisms on tangent cones, so if $(X,p)$ is etale locally isomorphic to $(Y,q)$, then $TC_pX\cong TC_qY$.  In particular, if $(Y,q)$ is itself a cone, then it must be the tangent cone to $X$ at $p$.  My question is about a partial converse to this statement.

Question:  When is $(X,p)$ etale locally isomorphic to $(TC_pX,0)$?

(Note:  This question is a reformulation of [Local intersection cohomology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186289/local-intersection-cohomology) without the intersection cohomology, which may have scared people off.)

Comment: By "when", do you mean "what's a reasonable sufficient condition"? (Not that I have one to give.)